# Select specific year from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have column which name is `date`. This column's format is like `D/M/Y` `(14/11/2016)`. I just want to select 2016 year. How can I do?

I'm using this code right now, what must I add?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: type is date... I'm Insert with thisdate("d/m/Y");

Comment: SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) from blog;

Comment: `WHERE YEAR(\`date\`)='2016'`

Comment: @shoaib `EXTRACT` works for date type field.

Comment: @Hamza yes type is date!

Answer (score 10):

Your query could be:

```
"SELECT * FROM blog WHERE YEAR(date)='2016' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

if your date column is a date data type. But since you are not using the standard mysql date format (YYYY-MM-DD) I guess it is not.

Please note that you are using a deprecated MYSQL_* API and you should switch to MYSQLI or PDO

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to not use mysql_query and switch to PDO or MySQLi instead but as per your problem:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2016 ORDER BY id DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2016 ORDER BY id DESC");
```

or

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE date >= "00/00/2016" AND date <= "31/12/2016" ORDER BY id DESC");
```

or

```
mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %m %Y') AS your_date FROM blog WHERE your_date LIKE "%2016" ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('14/11/2016', '%d/%m/%Y'));
```